Why is a Spring Modulith @ApplicationModuleListener not triggered when an event it listens to is published?
I'm trying to build a dummy POC, but I am missing something, that I can't figure out. The issue is that the method annotated with @ApplicationModuleListener is not triggered.
Here is my code:
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    String home() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private @NonNull final ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new MyApplicationEvent("HTTP_REQUEST" , request.getRequestURI()));
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Service
class MyApplicationModuleListener {

    @org.springframework.modulith.events.ApplicationModuleListener
    void on(MyApplicationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.message());
    }
}

record MyApplicationEvent(String type, String message) {}

Here are my Maven dependencies:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</parent>

…

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.modulith</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modulith-starter-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.modulith</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modulith-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
…

The weird thing is that the listener works when I said to replay events on the start-up, setting spring.modulith.republish-outstanding-events-on-restart=false.
Here is how the completion time of the event is null:

I pushed the code here https://github.com/jgarbora/poc-spring-modulith-events.

I found out that @ApplicationModuleListener is annotated with @TransactionalEventListener, which means that it's only triggered when a transaction is committed. So I ended up publishing the from event within a method annotated with @Transactional.
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventPublishingService {

  private @NonNull final ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  @Transactional
  public void publishEvent(MyApplicationEvent event) {
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
  }
}

and this did the trick.
